How do I find the absolute maximum and minimum values of the Lamb-Oseen Vortex?
I am researching alternative solutions to Stokes equations and I came across a problem with the Lamb-Oseen vortex I cannot solve that I hope will allow easier derivations of vortex functions with boundary conditions, such as restricting vortex growth and confining laminar radial flow. For example, if stirring coffee in a cup has a solution in cylindrical coordinates given ideal flow conditions, I want to find it mathematically and compare this behavior with experimental results.
For an angular velocity function derived by Navier-Stokes, $$ \omega \left(r,t\right)=\frac{\omega _0R_0^2}{R\left(t\right)^2}exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{R\left(t\right)^2}\right)$$
from which the azimuthal velocity $u_\theta$ component of the vector field in cylindrical coordinates, $\vec{u}$, derived by vorticity, $\vec{\omega }=\nabla \times \vec{u}= \nabla \times \vec{u_\theta}$, is the vortex function,
$$v_\theta (r,t)=\frac{\omega _0R_0^2}{r} \left ( 1- e^{-\frac{r^2}{R(t)^2}} \right )$$
This is equivalent to the Lamb Oseen equation for some $ \Gamma_0 = 2\omega_0 \pi R_{0}^2$, where, $\Gamma_0$ is the initial circulation.
Question: How do I find the max/min values of $u_\theta$ for all $R>0$ assuming that $R_{0}>0$ in $ R(t)=\sqrt{4\nu t +R_{0}^2}$?
So far, to find the $r$ locating the max, I have taken the partial derivative of $u_\theta$ w.r.t $r$, set this equal to zero, and attempted to solve for $r$ in, $$\frac{\partial u_{\theta }}{\partial r}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial u_{\theta }}{\partial r}=\omega _0R_0\left(-\frac{1}{r^2}+\frac{1}{r^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}}+\frac{2}{R^2}e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}}\right)=0$$ which reduces down to a seemingly unsolvable form.
$$\frac{r^2}{R^2}=ln\left(\frac{2r^2+R^2}{R^2}\right)$$
I looked into the Lambert W function, but haven't turned up algebraically exact solutions. Using the abs-max value for $\omega(r,t)$, $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}},\:\frac{\omega _0R_0^2}{R^2}\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}}\right),\left(-\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}},\:-\frac{\omega \:_0R_0^2}{R^2}\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}}\right)$$
I approximated for $u_\theta$ to be, $$\left(\pm \:\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)},\pm \:\frac{\omega \:_0R_0^2}{R^2}\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{2}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}\right)$$
Is there an exact set of solutions to $\frac{\partial u_{\theta }}{\partial r}=0$ ?


I'm returning a month later with suprising results that I hope serves pedagogical insight. The exact solution to the problem is the Lambert W function, with the substitution of solution $r$ as critical radius $q(t)$.
$$q=\pm \frac{\sqrt{-R^2 \left ( 2W_{n}\left ( -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{e}} \right )+1 \right )}}{\sqrt{2}}\approx \pm 1.12091R(t) \approx \pm R(t)\sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{5}}$$
I found the constant, $\sqrt{2\pi/5}$, experimentally to within 0.00819% of the true value of $q(t)$ for all values of $R(t)$. Interestingly, this constant is intrinsic to all renditions I've made of the Lamb-Oseen vortex, such as the confined vortex form, $$u_\theta (r,t)=\frac{\omega_0 R_{0}^2}{r}\left ( 1-e^{-\frac{r^2}{R^2}B(r)} \right )$$
with $B(r)$ being the boundary interaction function with a confinement radius, $R_f$ in $B(r)$.
